# Is there discrete Morse theory on acyclic categories?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Forman introduced discrete Morse theory on finite regular cell complexes. Minian introduced a version of discrete Morse theory for posets which generalizes Forman's original Morse theory https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1930. So I thought the following problem:

Is there a version of discrete Morse theory for acyclic categories which generalizes Minian's Morse theory?

A desire theorem (It is imaginary and is not logical and currect.) is that there is a "function (functor)" from an acyclic category such that the classifying space of the given acyclic category is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex such that the number of cells = the number of "critical objects".

An acyclic category is a small category in which only the identity morphisms have inverses and any morphism from an object to itself is an identity morphism. A poset $P$ is an acyclic category.

Comment: For reference: [Cross-posted from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364322).